# highchart background right side of hover marker

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Want to make a chart like this:

[image: chart]

I made almost of function, but I can't solve right side white opacity area.

[Here is a sample](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2016-election-forecast/?ex_cid=rrpromo#odds) of the picture (center of the link)

I think it's about X Axis Plotband.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: sorry I forgot. https://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/7177/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use zones to achieve opacity for some range of the line series - read [API docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.zones) for available options.

On load event, you can attach the function which adds mouse move event for the chart container. On mouse event, I get hover points and update their series zones.

```
Highcharts.addEvent(this.renderTo, 'mousemove', e => {
        const points = this.hoverPoints && this.hoverPoints.length && this.hoverPoints.slice();
        const hoverPoint = this.hoverPoint;



        if (points && hoverPoint) {
          const makeColor = Highcharts.color;
          const pos = hoverPoint.x;

          points.forEach(point => {
            const x = point.x;
            const color = point.color;
            point.series.update({
              zones: [{
                value: x
              }, {
                color: makeColor(point.color).setOpacity(0.3).get()
              }]
            }, false)
          });

          this.redraw(false);
```

That allows to get the right opacity for the series, but your tooltip will disappear because of the redraw and series update. It is needed to call `tooltip.refresh()` but you also need to find the points for the param of `tooltip.refresh()`

```
 const ps = [];
          this.series.forEach(series => {
            ps.push(series.points.find(point => point.x === pos))
          });
          this.tooltip.refresh(ps, e);
```

You can add some other functionality like reseting zones if you are outside the plot area. Complete example is in the fiddle.

#### Example and output

https://jsfiddle.net/qyjxzepu/

[image: opacity chart]